# Spark not cleaning state rows when doing a join between 2 streams

Tags: apache-spark, join, stream, watermark

We are using Spark Structured Streaming version 3.2.2. We are doing a join between 2 data streams, we tried to 2 different ways.
The first one uses a static value for the time-constraint interval and works fine.

```
    val slide = "1 hour"
    inputMetrics
      .join(
        inputStats
          .withColumn("timestampWindowEnd", (col(""windowEnd") / 1000000000).cast("timestamp"))
          .withWatermark("timestampWindowEnd", watermarkReadStats),
        expr(
          s"""
          $THRESHOLD_RULE_ID_COLUMN = $ALGO_ID AND
          $METRIC_NAME_COLUMN = $METRIC_NAME AND
          $MSG_IN_TIME_COLUMN >= timestampWindowEnd  AND
          $MSG_IN_TIME_COLUMN < timestampWindowEnd  +  **interval $slide**
            """
        )
      )
```

Note: MSG_IN_TIME_COLUMN column from inputMetrics dataframe has a watermark

But when we want to make this slide value dynamic (can be different between input rows) and extract it from a column, application does not work properly and memory/number of state rows kept grows batch after batch. The code used is as follow:

```
    inputMetrics
      .join(
        inputStats
          .withColumn("timestampWindowEnd", (col(""windowEnd") / 1000000000).cast("timestamp"))
          .withWatermark("timestampWindowEnd", watermarkReadStats),
        expr(
          s"""
          $THRESHOLD_RULE_ID_COLUMN = $ALGO_ID AND
          $METRIC_NAME_COLUMN = $METRIC_NAME AND
          $MSG_IN_TIME_COLUMN > timestampWindowEnd    AND
          $MSG_IN_TIME_COLUMN <= timestampWindowEnd  + **make_interval(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, $SLIDE_COLUMN)**
            """
        )
      )
```

Does Spark support this dynamic interval ? Should we write it in an other way ?